# Why am I getting "Attribute cannot be read HRESULT : 0x80650002" in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am getting exception Attribute cannot be read HRESULT : 0x80650002 from the following line:-

GattReadResult readResult = await tempMeasurementCharacterisitic[0].ReadValueAsync();

How to solve this problem. I am doing this for HealthThermometer. Characteristic UUID 0x2A1C

Comment: Any Explanation for negative vote?

Answer (score 2):

Got that. The problem is that the characteristic I am trying to read is not allowed by this particular service to be read. If you see specification of bluetooth helath thermometer service, u can see that characteristic uuid 0x2A1C cannot be read. However you are allowed to use indicate method. So instead of reading use characteritic.valuechanged += value_change_event_handler;